# Firebase warning: Using an unspecified index when search data with Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I built a Firebase Cloud Function that looks for users who has value of 'IsNotificationEnabled' equal to true .
Part of my Function

```
export const sendPushNotification = functions.https
.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { message } = req.body;
        var usersRef = firebase.ref('/Users');
        var usersPushNotificationTokensRef = firebase.ref('/PushNotificationTokens')

        var listUsersSendNotifications = [],
            usersWithTokenSendNotifications = [],
            promises = [];
        if (message) {
            await usersRef.orderByChild('IsNotificationEnabled').equalTo(true).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                    console.log(childSnapshot.key)
                    listUsersSendNotifications.push(childSnapshot.key)

                    return false;
                })
            })
            ..........................
```

as you can see here I'm looking users where IsNotificationEnabled = true. when I run it I get in logs

> [2018-05-22T09:12:57.352Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING:
>   Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered
>   on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "IsNotificationEnabled" at
>   /Users to your security rules for better performance.

the rules I insert in firebase console

```
    {
  "rules": {
     ".indexOn": ["IsNotificationEnabled"],

    "Users":{
      "$uid":{
      ".indexOn": ["IsNotificationEnabled"],
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }


    },
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the question in your question. But doesn't the indexon need to be one level higher? Below Users instead of $uid.

Comment: my question, why I get this error and how to fix it. I edited my post and add image of users structure

Comment: Did you try putting the indexon below users instead of $uid?

Comment: yes, it works now. thank you sir.

Answer (score 7):

As the message says, you'll need to add the index to `/Users`. You're now adding it one level lower, where it won't work.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users":{
      ".indexOn": ["IsNotificationEnabled"]
    },
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I find it easiest to remember where to define an index by thinking of where I run my query. Since your query runs on `/Users`, you need to define your index on that level.

I also remove your `.read` and `.write` rules on `/Users/$uid`, since they are ineffective. You're granting full read/write access at the root already, and permission cannot be taken away at a lower level.

Comment: Hey, I want to understand. I will remove the read and write to root because I want just users with uid can write and read. in addition, when I read data from firebase function, do I need to write as you show me in your answers? because isNotificationEnabled  is under each userid in my app. Users/random_key/isNotificationEnabled

Comment: As I said: you need to define your index in the place where you run the query. Since you query `/Users`, you'll need to add the index to `/Users`.

Comment: Note that removing the root `".read": true` will ensure that your query fails, since [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). If you want to be able to read from `/Users`, you must have read permission on `/Users`.