# How to search a value in Firebase IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a problem with `queryOrdered()` function, I don't know really how to deal with...

Assuming my database structure is :

```
Planes{
Uid{
    SE{
        AutoID{
            .Auto-Id
            .Picture
            .Registration
            .Type
            .model
        }
        AutoID{
            //Same as first one
        }
    }
    ME{
        AutoID{
            //Same as first one
        }
    }
}}
```

In this part of my Database I would like to run a search by `.Registration`

So I've been set my reference to `Planes > UId`

And after do this code :

```
var acftPickerSelected = aircrafts[listAcftsPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser{
        // user is connect
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let ev = ref.child("Planes").child(userID!)

        ev.queryOrdered(byChild: "Registration").queryEqual(toValue: acftPickerSelected).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                self.pickerRegi = value?["Registration"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."
                self.stdbPickerType = value?["Type"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."
                self.pickerModel = value?["model"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."

                print("Avion : \(self.pickerRegi) - \(self.pickerModel) - \(self.stdbPickerType)")
            }
        }
```

But this message appears :

> 2018-11-27 18:03:54.797824+0100 XXXXXXXXXX[12954:527986] 5.10.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB034028] Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Registration" at /Planes/BJMhmQzJXldULc5X9Y2WzjFEs9a2 to your security rules for better performance

So I've been add the rules on firebase like this :

```
{"rules": {
"Planes":{
  "$uid":{
  ".indexOn": ["Registration"],
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
},
".read": true,
".write": true}}
```

And now the error message didn't appear anymore but nothing happen in this part :

```
self.pickerRegi = value?["Registration"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."
            self.stdbPickerType = value?["Type"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."
            self.pickerModel = value?["model"] as? String ?? "..unknown.."

            print("Avion : \(self.pickerRegi) - \(self.pickerModel) - \(self.stdbPickerType)")
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase warning: Using an unspecified index when search data with Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464080/firebase-warning-using-an-unspecified-index-when-search-data-with-firebase-clou)

Comment: @Callam That's a good link but not a duplicate as the OP resolved the issue as noted in the post and it's not the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here;

1. indexOn
2. The observer

and in this case, the indexOn is not the issue.

The indexOn is most important in a production app and it's basically a performance increase for queries. For testing, eliminate that variable first as it's not the cause of the issue. Reset the rules to default temporarily

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

The real issue is the observe as it's not deep enough to reach the data you're trying to get to. You're missing the 'SE' level. Here's a re-write

```
let uidRef = ref.child("Planes").child(userID)
let seRef = uidRef.child("SE") //this is the child node to query
seRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "Registration").queryEqual(toValue: acftPickerSelected)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
      for child in snapshot.children {
          let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
          let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
          let reg = dict["Registration"] as? String ?? "No Reg"
          let mod = dict["model"] as? String ?? "No Model"
          print(reg, mod)
      }
}
```

the way it's written in your question, the query will query the next level up: it's expecting to find a Registration node directly under the SE and ME nodes. But those nodes only contain the autoId nodes.

EDIT:

Changing the structure by flattening (denormalizing) it would also be another option

```
Planes
   Uid
      AutoID
         .Auto-Id //note, if the is the same as the key, its not needed
         .Picture
         .Registration
         .Type
         .model
         .se_or_me: "SE"
      AutoID
         .Auto-Id
         .Picture
         .Registration
         .Type
         .model
         .se_or_me: "ME"
```

Comment: Thanks, so as I need to check both folder (SE & ME) at the same time I need to do two check one for the SE folder and one for the ME folder ?

Comment: @flyer74 With your current structure, that is correct. I don't know why there are two nodes (SE and ME) so it may simply be a matter of changing your structure to make it flatter (demormalizing) and include that as a child node instead of making it a parent node. So within the uid parent node you would have each child node include what you have now, .picture and .registration etc but also have a .se_or_me: "SE" or .se_or_me: "ME". I added an edit to my answer to demonstrate that structure.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'll try it but I also have a TableView in an other View witch is divided by 2 sections one for SE and one for ME I need to modify this section also ..

Comment: @flyer74 If you opt to change your structure to include a .se_or_me child then it won't matter because the child nodes contain SE or ME so you would know which it belongs to or can filter by that child node.

Comment: I've been change my database and your code work very well ! Thanks !!!!

Comment: @flyer74 Awesome! I am glad it helped. Be sure to accept the answer so it can help others as well!