# query in firebase realtime database is very slow

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have 30000 data in my realtime database ,the query takes a long time in first after that it being  fast.

my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "iBkHop2321":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "false",
          ".write": "true"
      }
    },
      "contacts":{
        ".read":"root.child('iBkHop2321').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
          ".write":"root.child('iBkHop2321').child(auth.uid).val() === true"
      }   
}
}
```

my data:

```
{
  "contacts" : {
    "-Moj9LK306LUDCXIbypG" : {
         "-Moj9LK5rgNYVcD1PJ2S" : {
          "android_id" : "312e62167b076ce1",
          "mobile" : "770966855",
          "name" : "عبدالله سيلان / فرع اب الشركة"
          },
         "-Moj9LKEZgZqu8tyW-4c" : {
          "android_id" : "312e62167b076ce1",
          "mobile" : "711237507",
          "name" : "عبد الملك عمر / الهلال للصرافة تعز"
         },
         "-Moj9LKFmA0E6jJMuWfD" : {
          "android_id" : "312e62167b076ce1",
          "mobile" : "711290007",
          "name" : "احمد هاشم /ايتي عدن للصرافة"
         },
         .
         .
         .
    "-MopGM8c8Fosxb0WKJpx" : {
         .
         . 
    }
    .
    .
  "iBkHop2321" : {
    "026Z0V8ad8MnJtnfn9qt6atgMWS2" : true,
    "0CDjvZBoWNO0zAxg8qt9M4n4Lgg2" : true,
    "10sILZEGXnP4v1kYwaeiFUZ1Ziw2" : true,
    "1QBZjbO5vmSNmmYwDcNmmpJ0AdN2" : true,
    "1p0dUGTEChXIqk0PfSZYVcPsSRD3" : true,
    "1ur5x65ZIeUpT38FTt1oZ6ICG383" : true,
     .
     .
     .
     .  
}
```

and this the query:

```
public void newSearch(String mobile){
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
    ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayContacts arrayContacts = new ArrayContacts(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayContacts);
    showProgressDialogWithTitle("يرجى الانتظار");
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                String uidKey  = ds.getKey();
                assert uidKey != null;
                DatabaseReference ref = myRef.child(uidKey);
                Query query=ref.orderByChild("mobile").startAt(mobile).endAt(mobile+"\uf8ff").limitToFirst(20);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {

                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Contacts value = snapshot1.getValue(Contacts.class);
                                arrayList.add(value);
                            }
                            ArrayContacts arrayContacts = new ArrayContacts(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
                            listView.setAdapter(arrayContacts);
                            hideProgressDialogWithTitle();

                        }
                        else {
                            hideProgressDialogWithTitle();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "children cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "parent cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

when i lunch the app the Query is very slow after that the Query becomes very fast!

please help me

**Edit:**
the first data load takes longer than one min is this normal?
Is my tree good and my rules?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It is normal that the first data load takes longer than subsequent data loads, as the SDK needs to find the server and establish the connection to the server. If you think you're seeing unreasonable load times beyond that, please edit your question to show what you measured.

Comment: 1) Instead of telling is that it takes a minute, measure the exact time in your code and then log it. If you then include both the updated code and its output in your question, we'll all be looking at the same thing. 2) Also make sure to include other details that we can't know. How much JSON data is being loaded? What is the bandwidth of the device that you test this on? How much faster is it when you retrieve the same data the second time? Are there any relevant message showing in your logcat output when the data is being loaded?

Comment: Hi, In fact the application is installed at 60 users and they are using it  and complain from the duration of the load,! >>>Data is often downloaded quickly

Comment: see the question i edited it.

Comment: i found this message:         2021-11-21 23:26:36.393 20414-22248/com.ibkh.contactsapp W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "name"' at contacts/-MojA-Y5-7QzeH6Olmqs to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Comment: So, did you add that `.indexOn` yet? Or [search for the message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+Using+an+unspecified+index.+Your+data+will+be+downloaded+and+filtered+on+the+client.+Consider+adding+%27%22.indexOn%22), which should quickly lead you to a solution, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50469625

Comment: I added it, But nothing has changed, query become fast when i use  . LimitToFirst(5), i need to query all not limited.

Comment: If loading the data still takes long even after adding the index, you're loading too much data for the connection speed.